# Find timestamp closest to one hour ago in a list

Tags: c#, list, search

So I have a list of timestamps, they're not uniformly spaced meaning one time stamp can be 10 minutes after the previous or 5 seconds after. What's the best way to find the index of the entry that is closest to (DateTime.Now.TotalSeconds - 3600)?

Comment: Two comments: 1. timestamp is not a well-known type. Do you mean `DateTime` objects, or do you have a user defined type? 2. It may be more readable to express 'one hour ago' as: `DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));`

Comment: Yea sorry I used `DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch` to create a unix timestamp which I'm using as a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't gave any specific code, we can only do suggestions on that.

What you can do, is take the absolute difference of the date in the list and compare that to the desired date, taking the lowest.

Something like:

```
list.OrderBy( x => Math.Abs((x.Date - desiredDate).TotalMilliseconds)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without ordering the list? I wanna keep the original order in tact. I could make a copy of the list but the  list has the potential to have 17k entries :/

Comment: The `OrderBy` creates a copy, so it should suit your needs.

Comment: Also, with 17k results, isn't it easier to sort it in the actual source? Maybe a database?

Comment: Well it has the potential, but I've taken steps to keep the list below 4k entries. The list is of a sample and a timestamp. If the sample matches a sample already in the list it doesn't add it to the list. Also the frequency of the samples is adjustable so it'd only create 17k entries if all 17k samples are unique and the samples are taken every 5s for a day.

Comment: I used this `IOrderedEnumerable<Sample> atest = _avgHalf.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.Date - (DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds - 3600)));` But when I list the results, the first result is further from 1 hour ago and closer to the present time. 1410731677 then 1410731664

Comment: Figured it out. Silly mathematical mistake. It should have been `Now - Date - 3600`, not `Date - Now - 3600`. It works well thanks!